# StopIteration from "yield from"

Tags: python-3.x

Newbie to generator here. My understanding is that when breaking from a generator function ( `total_average`), it will implicitly trigger `StopIteration` in `wrap_average`. But `wrap_average` will return None back to the caller, and the program should not see `StopIteration`.

```
def total_average():
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    avg = None
    print("starting average generator")
    while True:
        num = yield avg
        if num is None:
            break
        total += num
        count += 1
        avg = total/count

def wrap_average(average_generator):
    """This is just a pipe to the generator"""
    print("starting wrap_average")
    avg = yield from average_generator

# Note: total_average() is the generator object. total_average is generator function
w = wrap_average(total_average())
# Execute everthing until hitting the first iterator. None being returned
print("starting the generator: ", next(w))
print(w.send(3))
print(w.send(4))
# Finish Coroutine
# ? Not sure why w.send(None) is giving me stop iteration?
w.send(None)
```

However, Python 3.8 shows an `StopIteration` error. I'm not sure why?

Comment: `But wrap_average will return None back to the caller, and the program should not see StopIteration.` `wrap_average` is a generator, hence this exception is thrown. The return value doesn't matter.

Comment: "But wrap_average will return None back to the caller," No, `wrap_average` is a generator function, it returns a *generator object*.

Answer (score 2):

The `yield from` in `wrap_average` does catch the `StopIteration` from `total_average`, but that's not the only `StopIteration` here, because `total_average` isn't the only generator.

`wrap_average` is **also a generator**. When it ends, it too raises a `StopIteration`. *That's* the `StopIteration` you get from the final `send`.

Comment: Neither `wrap_average` nor `total_average` are generators. Both are generator *functions* that *return* `generator` objects.

Comment: @chepner: "Generator" can refer to either a generator function or a generator iterator. The usage isn't really consistent.

Comment: You'll see routines like `inspect.isgenerator` that test for generator iterators, but you'll also see things like the [Python glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19) for "generator" saying "Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator iterator in some contexts."